# An isomorphism between $\mathbb F_2(\alpha )$ and $\mathbb F_2(\beta )$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

We know that $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ and $g(x)=x^3+x^2+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb F_2$. Let $\alpha $ a root of $f$ and $\beta $ a root of $g$. Let $K=\mathbb F_2(\alpha )$ and $L=\mathbb F_2(\beta )$. Find explicitely an isomorphism between $K$ and $L$.

**Attempts**

Does $\alpha \longmapsto \beta $ work ? It look to easy. If not, how can I do ?

Comment: No it doesn't work. Note that $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_{2^{3}}$

Comment: Look for generators of the multiplicative group of each field.

Comment: @Joppy In general there are $\phi(p^k-1)$ generators. I think there is a better way, using the Galois group maybe.

Comment: @user1952009: you're right, that was a silly suggestion, my apologies.

Comment: You can easily show that $1/\alpha$ is a zero of $g(x)$ because
$$g(x)=x^3 f(\frac1x).$$ This exact question has been handled on our site before, but I don't have the time to search for an earlier incarnation now. Using *reciprocal polynomial* as a buzzword probably gives you some hits :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. You have to find all roots of the polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$. In fact, for $x^3+x+1$ all roots are given by $\alpha$, $\alpha^2,\alpha^2+\alpha$.

Comment: Thank your for your link, it really help. But I don't understand why we need the roots of $x^3+x^2+1$ over $\mathbb F_2(\alpha )$... To me $\mathbb F_2(\alpha )$ and $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$ are two finite field of same cardinal, so we just need to associate to each element of $\mathbb F_2(\alpha )$ an element of $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$... I'm sorry, but I don't see the subtlety here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to map $\alpha$ to a root of the polynomial $x^3 + x + 1$ in $\Bbb F(\beta)$.

You can just try them all: $\Bbb F(\beta)$ has $8$ elements, $0, 1, \beta$ are not a root, so there are $5$ candidates left and $3$ of them are a root.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: check that $\beta+1$ satisfies the polynomial $f(x)$ for $\alpha$.